# nginx not running .php through FastCGI

Tags: php, nginx, fastcgi

What am I doing wrong here? My config is as follows:

```
server {
listen        80;
server_name   internal.lan;

access_log /var/log/nginx/int-access.log;
error_log  /var/log/nginx/int-error.log;
root       /var/www/int;

location ~ \.php$ {
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
}
}
```

I've checked that the socket exists at the path in question, but any PHP files just get presented as plain text.

Probably a very simple one as I've never configured PHP with a server besides Apache before; can anyone help? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short tags were the problem.

`<?` to `<?php` fixed this.

Answer (score 0):

Ah we had problems like this a dozen of times. The solution was for us to put php and nginx under the same user group.

Comment: Would the group be necessary? As far as I can see, both are running under the www-data user.

Comment: Well that was our first problem. Looking at our .conf file I can see one more difference though: we use `fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;` to pass the request to php. I hope it helps.